# How to force page open dark theme of browser in react component

Tags: reactjs

I want all users see scrollbars as its in dark mode of chrome:

[image]

But some users don't use dark theme in chrome so I set colorSchema:"dark" of parent div style and it looks like this:

[image]

Why is it different from original dark style? How to use the schema with strong dark as shown in the first screenshot?

I know there is custom css solution to change scrollbar css. It's ok, but I am using reactjs, is it possible to style scroll bar in react component file?

```
const PARENTDIV: React.CSSProperties = {
  backgroundColor: color.quizBackground,
  flex: 1,
  colorScheme: 'dark',
}
```